# How to map List of Enums to MySQLs SET data type?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Having enum on Java side:

```
public enum MyTypes {
    TYPE1,
    TYPE2,
    TYPE3;
}
```

and an entity property, having list of them:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
    // other columns skipped

    @Column("types")
    // missing annotations here!?
    private List<MyTypes> types;

    // setters, getters...
}
```

On MySQL side, column `MY_TABLE`.`types`, defined as `set`:

```
`types`  set('TYPE1', 'TYPE2', 'TYPE3') NOT NULL
```

How to map properly `MyEntity.types` to `MY_TABLE.types`?

Comment: You misunderstood between set and enum, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html vs http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html

Comment: No, I didn`t. This is intentional - in my application logic, the entity can have one or few entries of MyTypes assigned to it at once, so therefore it has list of enums. On DB side I want to map it to single SET column, so I don`t need an additional relation table.

Comment: consider using a flags enum. otherwise you have to implement a UserType.